# AWS EMR: Error parsing parameter: Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create a cluster from inside one of my `EC2 instances`. Typing the following command to start my cluster-

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.20.0 --instance-groups instance-groups.json --auto-terminate and so on...
```

I receive the following error-

```
Error parsing parameter '--instance-groups': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
instance-groups.json
                    ^
```

I already tried `--instance-groups=instance-groups.json`, but I get the same error message.

What's wrong here?

Comment: I also get this same error message using aws textract

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The reason this was failing was because AWS has strict rules when it comes to providing the path for reading files within your EC2 instance.

So, if you want to read the file `instance-groups.json` (assuming it is in the same directory from where you're running the `aws emr` CLI command), you **must** provide `file://instance-groups.json` as the filename, instead of the straightforward `instance-groups.json`.

Answer (score 3):

Got this same error message for importing a JSON file in AWS DynamoDB, I was trying to import it from an S3 bucket.

> Error parsing parameter '--instance-groups': Expected: '=', received:
> 'EOF' for input: instance-groups.json

The issues got fixed when I moved file locally and executed the command with file://

So thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide like:-

--key Name=123456789

Answer (score 1):

Had similar error as "Expected: ',', received: 'EOF' for input:". I noticed there was a string with space in one of my arguments. Fixed the space issue and it was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

> --lifecycle-configuration file://C:/Users/MyUser/Desktop/AMZ/lifecycle.json

This way works too.