# Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Expected: '=', received: ' ' for input:

Tags: powershell, aws-cli, amazon-route53

I want to update the CNAME record. I am getting `Error parsing parameter '--change-batch': Expected: '=', received: ' ' for input:` when I run the below powershell script. I see a similar error mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55190873/740756) for another aws command. I verified that I am using `file://` as suggested there. I also saw another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60088045/740756) and I verified that I don't have a preceding or succeeding double or single quote. I was able to verify the json data and ensured that the file is present in the same directory. I can't figure out what is going on. Any helps are appreciated. My powershell script is below.

```
$json = '{"Changes": [{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "dev.mydns.com","Type": "CNAME","TTL": 300,"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": "s-########1.server.transfer.us-east-1.amazonaws.com."}]}},{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "qa.mydns.com","Type": "CNAME","TTL": 300,"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": "s-########2.server.transfer.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"}]}},{"Action": "UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet": {"Name": "uat.mydns.com","Type": "CNAME","TTL": 300,"ResourceRecords": [{"Value": "s-########3.server.transfer.us-east-1.amazonaws.com."}]}}]}'
$json | Out-File "route_update.json"

#I was able to get the file content and print using below commands

<#
$jsondata = Get-Content -Raw -Path route_update.json 
Write-Host $jsondata
#>

aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <ZoneId> --change-batch file://route_update.json
```

Comment: As the error says, it's expecting a `=` and not a blank space: `--change-batch=file://route_update.json`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: That's not true. I picked the above example from [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html#examples).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a JSON file, the format for the relative path (macOS/Linux) is;

```
--change-batch file://./dnsUpdates.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to go ahead with directly using the json string.

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id <ZoneId> --change-batch '{\"Changes\": [{\"Action\": \"UPSERT\",\"ResourceRecordSet\": {\"Name\": \"dev.mydns.com\",\"Type\": \"CNAME\",\"TTL\": 300,\"ResourceRecords\": [{\"Value\": \"s-########1.server.transfer.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.\"}]}}]}'
```