# What is wrong with my CircleCI config.yml S3 location file?

Tags: amazon-s3, continuous-integration, circleci, cicd, aws-code-deploy

Script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail

aws deploy create-deployment \
  --application-name s3_circle_ci \
  --deployment-group-name s3_circle_group \
  --file-exists-behavior OVERWRITE \
  --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime \
  --s3-location s3://logixpro-wms/WMS_LogixPro.zip \
```

Error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--s3-location': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
s3://logixpro-wms/WMS_LogixPro.zip
                                  ^

Exited with code exit status 252
CircleCI received exit code 252
```

I've tried:

- `--s3-location=s3://logixpro-wms/WMS_LogixPro.zip`
- `--s3-location=file://logixpro-wms/WMS_LogixPro.zip`

But they don't work. I don't know what's wrong and haven't been able to find an answer.

Comment: Is that the complete command in your script? If yes, you have a trailing backslash \ at the end. You need to remove that.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't help either.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190301/aws-emr-error-parsing-parameter-expected-received-eof-for-input